# Question regarding the Quotient Rule, How does the textbook reach this intermediate step?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)’ &= \frac{(x-3)^{1/3}\frac{1}{2}(x+2)^{-1/2}}{(x-3)^{2/3}} - \frac{(x+2)^{1/2}\frac{1}{3}(x-3)^{-2/3}}{(x-3)^{2/3}}\\
&= \frac{(x-3)^{-2/3}(x+2)^{-1/2}}{(x-3)^{2/3}}\cdot\left[\frac{1}{2}(x-3) - \frac{1}{3}(x+2)\right]
\end{align*}$$

Can someone advise how they got to the step after the second equality sign? Step by Step would be most helpful.

Comment: $(X-3)^{1/3}=(X-3)(X-3)^{-2/3}$

Comment: Please don’t use images for key parts of your post. They are not searchable, and some screen readers are unable to work with them. Here is a [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to typeset equations in this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{(x-3)^{1/3}\frac12(x+2)^{-1/2}}{(x-3)^{2/3}}-\dfrac{(x+2)^{1/2}\frac13(x-3)^{-2/3}}{(x-3)^{2/3}}$$

$$=\dfrac{(x-3)\color{blue}{(x-3)^{-2/3}}{\frac12\color{blue}{(x+2)^{-1/2}}}-(x+2)\color{blue}{(x+2)^{-1/2}}\frac13\color{blue}{(x-3)^{-2/3}}}{(x-3)^{2/3}}$$

$$=\dfrac{\color{blue}{(x-3)^{-2/3}(x+2)^{-1/2}}}{(x-3)^{2/3}}\left[\frac12(x-3)-\frac13(x+2)\right].$$

Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can see its correct, I just don't understand how you get to the final step. I  tried moving the negative exponents to the denominator and also multiplying out the brackets but I still don't manage to get your final answer.

Comment: Keep the denominator as is.  Just undistribute $(x-3)^{-2/3}(x+2)^{-1/2}$ in the numerator.  I added some color to help you see what I mean.  If you still don't follow, I could edit to include further details

Comment: Ah yes! I've got it, thank you!